# Does TiDB recommend reading and writing separation? And why

Tags: tidb

Not found in https://pingcap.com/ about this, but our DBA suggested that I do this, reading and writing separation

Answer (score 1):

It is fine to mix read and write workloads in one TiDB cluster, because it is designed to support both OLTP and OLAP scenarios.

For OLTP scenarios, TiDB requires high I/O disks for data access and operation. See more: https://pingcap.com/docs/FAQ/#does-tikv-support-sas-sata-disks-or-mixed-deployment-of-ssd-sas-disks